# Laptop hangs for approximately 2 minutes upon sign-in

Tags: release-loki, hardware

I have a System76 Galago Pro. Upon booting the laptop and logging in, the laptop hangs on a screen showing only the desktop wallpaper for about 2 minutes before loading the desktop.

One thing to note is that I do have home folder encryption enabled, in case that might be the issue, but it really shouldn't because the laptop have an nvme ssd.

I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this?

I thought it could be a duplicate of this issue, but the issue seems to describe the laptop never finishing booting, which mine does:

[Nothing but wallpaper shows up after login](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/571/nothing-but-wallpaper-shows-up-after-login)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a known issue, that many of us encountered already. Please run this command from the terminal.

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

let me know if it helps