# Only wallpaper after login

Tags: release-loki, desktop, pantheon

I have fresh installation of Elementary OS and have a problem that can't handle.

After system boot I have login page and when I type my password, login page dissapear, there is only wallpaper nothing more, no top toolbar and dock.

I've reinstalled pantheon also `rename /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop to /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled` doesn't help.

Have you any suggestions to resolve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A similar thing happens with me, but after maybe 1min/30sec it appears all normal. I thing this only happen when i installed the nvidia graphics??? i really don't remember.
Wait sometime like me to see if it appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do `sudo service lightdm restart` from terminal (you can access it by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. This will restart the display manager.

You can also try another solution taken from [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/772/12200).

Uninstall pantheon:

```
sudo apt-get remove pantheon
```

Reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install pantheon
```

And then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```